# How can I remove visual effect on pictures' slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to delete or change the JS and CSS codes to completely remove that visual thing center of the images, but it gives me a broken slideshow. I just need original pictures with buttons to move between photos.
it should be this part:

```
function initPrism_() {

masks.forEach(function(mask, i) {
  // Generate reference name.
  var name = 'mask_' + i;

  instances[name] = new PrismSlider({
    container: container,
    slides: slides,
    mask: mask, // Here is the mask object.
    duration: duration,
    easing: easing
  });
```

here's the original link:
https://codepen.io/vkanet/pen/NqyeEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can comment out `initPrism_()` line 107 in the `init()` function.

This will keep the sliders but remove the mask.

Comment: Thanks, dude! I thought I should change many things to disable the mask. I really appreciated it.